# conditional inside a Makefile target

Tags: makefile, conditional-statements

This a Makefile:

```
all:
    ifeq (0,0)
    echo hello
    endif
```

Note: there is a tab before `if`, `echo`, and `endif`.

Giving `make` I get:

```
ifeq (0,0)
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `0,0'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `ifeq (0,0)'
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 1
```

Why is it so?

Comment: Because content indented with TAB is provided to the shell to run, but `ifeq` is makefile syntax, not shell syntax.

Comment: @MadScientist Ahh, now I see, thank you! If you convert it to an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I think Beta will probably adjust his answer; I think he just didn't recognize the `ifeq (0,0)` syntax you were using.

Comment: @MadScientist: **[facepalm]** You caught it, you should answer.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that each line in a recipe runs in its own subshell, so the entire conditional must be in one line or it won't work. I'm not sure which shell you're using, but I presume you've tested this conditional on the command line and it works:

```
ifeq (0,0)
echo hello
endif
```

Without the right shell I can't test it, but I think you could also do something like this:

```
ifeq (0,0); echo hello; endif
```

If so, then it will also work in the makefile:

```
all:
    ifeq (0,0); echo hello; endif
```

The lines can then be wrapped using backslashes:

```
all:
    ifeq (0,0);\
   echo hello;\
   endif
```

(Note that the only TAB needed is before the `ifeq`.)

Comment: Still same error: ```/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `0,0'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `ifeq (0,0);\'```

Comment: He's trying to use GNU make's `ifeq` conditional, not a shell conditional...